# One-time database shrinking with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database

How can we decrease the DB files size when removing lots of outdated data?

We have an application that has data collected over many years. Now one customer has left the project and theirs data can be dropped. This customer alone stands for 75% of the data in the database.

The disk usage is very high, and running in a virtualized cloud service where the pricing is VERY high. Changing to another provider is not an option, and buying more disk is not popular since we have in practice 75% less data in use.

In my opinion it would be great if we could get rid of this customer data, shrink the files and be safe for years to come for reaching this disk usage level again.

I have seen many threads warning for performance decrease due to index fragmentation.

So, how can we drop this customer's data (stored in the same tables that other customers use, indexed on customer id among other things) without causing any considerable drawbacks?

Is these steps the way to go, or are there better ways?

1. Delete this customer's data
2. DBCC SHRINKDATABASE (database,30)
3. ALTER DATABASE database SET RECOVERY SIMPLE
4. DBCC SHRINKFILE (database_Log, 50)
5. ALTER DATABASE database SET RECOVERY FULL
6. DBCC INDEXDEFRAG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only step 1 is required. Deleting data will free space within the database which can be reused for new data. You should also execute [`ALTER INDEX...REORGANIZE` or `ALTER INDEX...REORGANIZE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-index-transact-sql) [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-index-transact-sql) to compact indexes and distribute free space evenly throughout the indexes.

**EDIT:**

Since your cloud provider charges for disk space used, you'll need to shrink files to release space back to the OS and avoid incurring charges. Below are some tweaks to the steps you proposed, which can be customized according to your RPO requirements.

1. ALTER DATABASE ... SET RECOVERY SIMPLE (or BULK_LOGGED)
2. Delete this customer's data
3. DBCC SHRINKFILE (database_Data, 30) --repeat for each file to the desired size
4. DBCC SHRINKFILE (database_Log, 50)
5. REORGANIZE (or REBUILD) indexes
6. ALTER DATABASE ... SET RECOVERY FULL
7. BACKUP DATABASE ...

Comment: But will that actually shrink the file sizes? Maybe I am totally wrong but I had the belief that deleting data  will create space within the file, not free actual disk space? For us, freeing disk space is of major interest since today we have 90+ % disk usage.

Comment: No, it will not shrink the physical file sizes but there is no need to.  There will be free space within the files that can be used for new data.

Comment: Ok, I am sorry I was unclear. The aim was to recover disk space. The customer using 75% of the data is for ever gone, so there will never be so much data again and there is a cost for used disk per month from the cloud provider. Decreasing disk usage is important.